# При успешной отправке запроса, перенаправление на страницу с благодарностью

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, form

Есть сайт, на котором расположена форма обратного звонка. При успешном заполнении полей, форма отправляется как положено, но уведомление показывается не так, как хотелось бы. При нажатии на кнопку "Отправить", окошко закрывается при помощи ajax (если я правильно понимаю) и показывается маленькая зелёная табличка с благодарностью. Подскажите, как реализовать вместо этого: при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить", перенаправляет на отдельную страницу, где я разверну более красивую благодарность. Я не силён в PHP, писал в тех поддержку данной темы, они сказали что изменить нужно в данном файле на 107 строчке (прикрепляю весь код из данного файла).

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        inquiry.init();
    });

    var inquiry = {

        init: function () {

            $('.contact-' + window.postType).on('click', function(event) {
                inquiry.showInquiryForm();
                event.preventDefault();
            }); 

            $('.cancel-' + window.postType + '-inquiry').on('click', function(event) {
                inquiry.hideInquiryForm();
                event.preventDefault();
            }); 

            $('.' + window.postType + '-inquiry-form').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                ignore: [],
                invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        var message = errors == 1 ? window.formSingleError : window.formMultipleError.format(errors);
                        $("div.error div p").html(message);
                        $("div.error").show();
                    } else {
                        $("div.error").hide();
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function() { inquiry.processInquiry(); }
            });

            $.each(window.inquiryFormFields, function(index, field) {
                if (field.hide !== '1') {
                    var $input = null;
                    if (field.type == 'text' || field.type == 'email') {
                        $input = $('.' + window.postType + '-inquiry-form').find('input[name=' + field.id + ']');
                    } else if (field.type == 'textarea') {
                        $input = $('.' + window.postType + '-inquiry-form').find('textarea[name=' + field.id + ']');
                    }

                    if ($input !== null && typeof($input) !== 'undefined') {
                        if (field.required == '1') {
                            $input.rules('add', {
                                required: true,
                                messages: {
                                    required: window.inquiryFormRequiredError
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (field.type == 'email') {
                            $input.rules('add', {
                                email: true,
                                messages: {
                                    required: window.inquiryFormEmailError
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },      
        showInquiryForm : function () {
            $('.three-fourth').hide();
            $('.right-sidebar').hide();
            $('.full-width.' + window.postType + '-inquiry-section').show();
        },
        hideInquiryForm : function () {
            $('.three-fourth').show();
            $('.right-sidebar').show();
            $('.full-width.' + window.postType + '-inquiry-section').hide();
        },
        processInquiry : function () {

            var cValS = $('#c_val_s_inq').val();
            var cVal1 = $('#c_val_1_inq').val();
            var cVal2 = $('#c_val_2_inq').val();

            var dataObj = {
                'action':'inquiry_ajax_request',
                'userId' : window.currentUserId,
                'postId' : window.postId,
                'c_val_s' : cValS,
                'c_val_1' : cVal1,
                'c_val_2' : cVal2,
                'nonce' : BYTAjax.nonce
            };

            $.each(window.inquiryFormFields, function(index, field) {
                if (field.hide !== '1') {
                    dataObj[field.id] = $('#' + field.id).val();
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: BYTAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: dataObj,
                success:function(data) {
                    if (data == 'captcha_error') {
                        $("div.error div p").html(window.InvalidCaptchaMessage);
                        $("div.error").show();
                    } else {
                        $("div.error div p").html('');
                        $("div.error").hide();
                        $('.contact-' + window.postType).hide(); // hide the button
                        inquiry.hideInquiryForm();
                        $('.inquiry-form-thank-you').show();
                    }
                },
                error: function(errorThrown) {

                }
            }); 
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это (106 - 110 строка)

```
$("div.error div p").html('');
$("div.error").hide();
$('.contact-' + window.postType).hide(); // hide the button
inquiry.hideInquiryForm();
$('.inquiry-form-thank-you').show();
```

заменить на (JQUERY синтаксис)

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```

или на (Native JS синтаксис)

```
document.location = 'http://google.com';
```

Где http://google.com -  полный путь к вашей странице

или заменить на (JQUERY синтаксис)

```
$(location).attr('href', 'other_page.php');
```

или на (Native JS синтаксис)

```
document.location = 'other_page.php';
```

Где other_page.php -  относительный путь (other_page.php  лежит в тойже папке где и скрипт)

Comment: Прошу прощение, но на мой взгляд использовать jquery для редиректа это перебор, http://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/4222611

Comment: если код уже написан на JQUERY - то писать код в одном стиле - не может являться перебором

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто после 111 строки:

```
$('.inquiry-form-thank-you').show();
```

добавить переадресацию через javascript:

```
document.location.href = 'http://адрес_для_перенаправления';
```

Comment: Добавил и ничего не помогло, не открывает новую страницу.

Comment: @Валерий Емельянов, потому-что javascript нужно выводить примерно так: `echo "<script> document.location.href = 'http://адрес_для_перенаправления';</script>"`

Comment: @Levelleor Всё ровно не открывает новую страницу.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов сайт доступен из сети? киньте ссылку.

Comment: @Olegatro http://sunnyge.com/hotel/gostevoj-dom-anakliya/

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельяно у вас код написан не правильно, в методе .show() зачем то прописан урл, перечитайте пож. повнимательнее ответ пользователя. Он ведь вам правильно всё написал. 
Т.е. должно быть `$('.inquiry-form-thank-you').show(); document.location.href='http://sunnyge.com/spasibo/';`

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов согласно одному из [ответов](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430948/4222611), лучше использовать `window.location.href` вместо `document.location.href`, но в любом случаи у вас код не правильный. Так же вы можете стереть строку `$('.inquiry-form-thank-you').show(); ` потому что она отвечает за отображение ответа. Но т.к потом срабатывает редирект, это не так важно. Есть эта строка или нет.

Comment: @Olegatro У него в ответе стояли пробелы, наверное по этому не сработало